What's the title of this sci-fi story about a sentient planet?
It's an early short sci-fi story. 1950 to 1960's maybe.
3 people are on an unusual planet that seems sentient. A young man, a young woman, and a little older man say 30 years old.
The young woman has a crush on the slightly older guy. He eventually kills her. This seems to bring about his healing and rehabilitation.
The planet, which speaks to the guests, explains that he is ready to leave.

This is Gene Wolfe's 1973 story The Death of Doctor Island (not to be confused with his stories The Island of Doctor Death or The Doctor of Death Island).
WolfeWiki says that the characters are:

Dr. Island — he is your "sentient planet" (although I remember it as being a small planetoid).
Nicholas Kenneth de Vore — he is the young man.
Diane Phillips — she is the young woman who gets killed.
Ignacio — he is the slightly older man.

If my memory is correct,
Dr. Island indeed manipulates Ignacio into killing Diane, in order to "heal" Ignacio.

Oh gosh, I can't believe you were able to name it. Years ago I had a small collection of sci-fi books as part of my larger Library which I re-homed as a result of a move with my wife and four kids.
This story has always haunted me and I wanted to reread it but I couldn't remember the name.
The ethical and metaphysical questions this story raises press upon me a bit more at this stage of life. The story was kind of creepy when I first read it.
Thank you so very much for taking the time to answer my question.

@Diego: Gene Wolfe was one of my favorite authors, so I've read a lot of stuff by him. I agree that this short story is creepy — Dr. Island is clearly evil, so one suspects that his "cure" of Ignacio maybe should not be taken at face value. I should probably reread the story and see whether I can figure out what's going on behind the scenes.

I just reread this story (it's available on archive.org). And I now think the cure of Ignacio should be taken at face value. I'm not sure it makes sense psychologically, but Dr. Island (not actually a sentient planet — a very powerful AI  that's plugged into the planetoid) does give some facile rationalizations for it, so it seems this story requires suspension of disbelief.

"The Death of Doctor Island (not to be confused with his stories The Island of Doctor Death or The Doctor of Death Island)" - why is Gene Wolfe so awesome?
